# Handling duplicate XML elements using ElementPath in SSRS

Tags: xml, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report using an XML data source which I try to pull data from to display in a report.  The problem is that the XML data can have duplicate elements in a section.  The problem part of the XML is this:

```
<ECPrograms>
  <FiscalEntityTypeCode>D</FiscalEntityTypeCode>
  <FiscalEntityCode>70000</FiscalEntityCode>
  <ECProgram>01</ECProgram>
  <ECProgramStartDate>2018-09-10</ECProgramStartDate>
  <ECDeliveryMethod>1</ECDeliveryMethod>
  <ECDeliverySchedule>05</ECDeliverySchedule>
  <FederalPovertyLevelQuintile>03</FederalPovertyLevelQuintile>
  <AdditionalEligibilityFactor>05</AdditionalEligibilityFactor>
  <AdditionalEligibilityFactor>07</AdditionalEligibilityFactor>
  <QualifyingFactor>D</QualifyingFactor>
</ECPrograms>
```

In some cases such as this, there are multiple values for "AdditionalEligibilityFactor" being generated.  The part of my ElementPath query that reads this is as follows:

```
ECPrograms{FiscalEntityTypeCode,FiscalEntityCode,ECProgram,ECProgramStartDate,ECDeliveryMethod,ECDeliverySchedule,FederalPovertyLevelQuintil,AdditionalEligibilityFactor,QualifyingFactor}}
```

The query runs without errors, and it returns data for everything until it reaches a ECPrograms section that has multiple values for AdditionalEligibilityFactor.  At that point is just no longer returns any values for AdditionalEligibilityFactor from then on, even if following ones only have one value.  The other data is returned just fine.

Is there any way to structure my ElementPath query to get that data for these duplicated elements somehow?